Using an Asynchronous Task Executor with an ItemStream Reader
Disclaimer:
The code i am sharing has been anonymised. 
Hello Community,
In my project we are using several spring batch jobs and have this warning in our log every time we start the spring application.
WARN FaultTolerantStepBuilder:501 Asynchronous TaskExecutor detected with ItemStream reader.
I narrowed down the particular job that the stepBuilder complains about and it uses a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor with a RepositoryItemReader.
The ItemReader extends one form of a StreamReader, which is why this exception is thrown (I think). We are using a faultTolerant Version of the stepBuilder.
I tried implementing a custom ItemReader, but it did not work because it was not ThreadSafe. Does anyone know wether:

This warning has done harm for them? (It has not done harm for us for now)
How to write a thread safe item reader or how to use a synchronous Task executor

Imagine the Batch Setup as follows:
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class GenericBatchConfig {
  public static final String GENERIC_JOB = "genericJob";

  private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
  private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
  private final GenericRepository genericRepository;
  private final ItemReader<String> reader;
  private final GenericWriter writer;
  private final UpdateDimensionTablesTasklet taslket;
  private final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;  // Async Executor

  @Value("${example.schedule." + GENERIC_JOB + ": 59 59 23 31 12 ? 2099}")
  private String cronExpression;

  @Value("${example.application.genericJobChunkSize}")
  private int chunkSize;

  @StepScope
  @Bean
  public RepositoryItemReader<String> reader() { // Not the custom reader, but how it was before i tried a custom reader which did not work
    RepositoryItemReader<String> repositoryItemReader = new RepositoryItemReader<>();

    repositoryItemReader.setRepository(genericRepository);
    repositoryItemReader.setMethodName("method");
    repositoryItemReader.setSort(Collections.singletonMap("id", Sort.Direction.ASC));
    repositoryItemReader.setPageSize(chunkSize);

    return repositoryItemReader;
  }

  @Bean
  public Trigger genericTrigger(@Qualifier("genericJobDetail") JobDetail genericJobDetail) {
    return TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
        .forJob(genericJobDetail)
        .withIdentity("genericTrigger")
        .withDescription("description")
        .withSchedule(cronSchedule(cronExpression))
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public JobDetail genericJobDetail() {
    return JobDetailBuilder.newJob()
        .withIdentity(GENERIC_JOB)
        .withDescription("description")
        .withJobName(GENERIC_JOB)
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Job genericJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory
        .get(GENERIC_JOB)
        .start(step1())
        .next(step2())
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory
        .get("taskletName")
        .tasklet(tasklet)
        .build();
  }

  private Step step2() {
    return stepBuilderFactory
        .get("stepName")
        .<String, String>chunk(chunkSize)
        .faultTolerant() // Here is the faultTolerant Builder
        .skipLimit(1000)
        .skip(Exception.class)
        .listener(new CustomSkipListener<>())
        .reader(reader)
        .writer(writer)
        .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
        .build();
  }
}

Please let me know if anyone had an issue like this before and how you solved it. There is a quite similar question to this under
Spring Batch "Asynchronous TaskExecutor detected with ItemStream reader"
But the setup is different.
Thank you

The warning is about using a stateful reader in a concurrent step. The state is used in a restart scenario. The issue that can happen is that threads will corrupt the state by concurrently modifying it. If you don't care about restartability, you can turn off the state (set saveState(false) on the reader) and safely ignore those warnings.
Restartability is not compatible with concurrency (ie concurrent steps), so you need to make a choice about which feature you want to keep. That said, you can use a partitioned step, which is restartable by design.
